# Dismiss a parent modal in SwiftUI from a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am aware of how to dismiss a modal from a child view using `@Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode / self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` but this is a different issue.

When you present a multi-page `NavigationView` in a modal window, and have navigated through a couple of pages, the reference to `presentationMode` changes to be the NavigationView, so using `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` simply pops the last NavigationView rather than dismissing the containing modal.

Is it possible - and if so how - to dismiss the containing modal from a page in a NavigationView tree?

Here's a simple example showing the problem. If you create an Xcode Single View app project using SwiftUI and replace the default `ContentView` code with this, it should work with no further changes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showModal: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.showModal.toggle()
    }) {
      Text("Launch Modal")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, onDismiss: {
      self.showModal = false
    }) {
      PageOneContent()
    }
  }
}

struct PageOneContent: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("I am Page One")
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page One")
      .navigationBarItems(
        trailing: NavigationLink(destination: PageTwoContent()) {
          Text("Next")
        })
      }
  }
}

struct PageTwoContent: View {

  @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("This should dismiss the modal. But it just pops the NavigationView")
          .padding()

        Button(action: {
          // How to dismiss parent modal here instead
          self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
          Text("Finish")
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page Two")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm learning swiftui from a couple of week, so I'm not sure, but did you try to replace "trailing: NavigationLink(destination: PageTwoContent()) {" with trailing: PageTwoContent() {   . Or delete NavigationView block inside PageTwoContent

Comment: @SimonePistecchia I'm afraid neither of your suggestions are appropriate but thanks anyway

Comment: Interesting... I'm getting exception with your snapshot `UIKit-3900.12.15/UINavigationController.m:8129
CRASH: Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.`. Aren't you?

Comment: @Asperi - no, it's working fine. Though I just made a change to make it work with a default Xcode SwiftUI project out of the box.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is possible approach based on usage own explicitly created environment key (actually I have feeling that it is not correct to use `presentationMode` for this use-case.. anyway).

Proposed approach is generic and works from any view in modal view hierarchy. Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

```
// define env key to store our modal mode values
struct ModalModeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = Binding<Bool>.constant(false) // < required
}

// define modalMode value
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var modalMode: Binding<Bool> {
        get {
            return self[ModalModeKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[ModalModeKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}


struct ParentModalTest: View {
  @State var showModal: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.showModal.toggle()
    }) {
      Text("Launch Modal")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, onDismiss: {
    }) {
      PageOneContent()
        .environment(\.modalMode, self.$showModal) // < bind modalMode
    }
  }
}

struct PageOneContent: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("I am Page One")
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page One")
      .navigationBarItems(
        trailing: NavigationLink(destination: PageTwoContent()) {
          Text("Next")
        })
      }
  }
}

struct PageTwoContent: View {

  @Environment (\.modalMode) var modalMode // << extract modalMode

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("This should dismiss the modal. But it just pops the NavigationView")
          .padding()

        Button(action: {
          self.modalMode.wrappedValue = false // << close modal
        }) {
          Text("Finish")
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page Two")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I can confirm this works perfectly. I'm just going to wait and see if there are any further approaches or comments on this approach but assuming no drawbacks, I will mark as the correct answer soon.

Answer (score 6):

Another Approach would be to simply use a notification for this case and just reset the triggering flag for your modal.
It is not the most beautiful solution for me but it is the solution I am most likely to still understand in a few months.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModalNav: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Present Modal")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                showModalNav.toggle()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showModalNav, content: {
                ModalNavView()
            }).onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "PushedViewNotifciation"))) { _ in
                showModalNav = false
            }
    }
}


struct ModalNavView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: PushedView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Show Another View")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct PushedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Pushed View").onTapGesture {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.init(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "PushedViewNotifciation")))
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to loosely couple the views through a notification you could also just use a binding for this like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModalNav: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Present Modal")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                showModalNav.toggle()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showModalNav, content: {
                ModalNavView(parentShowModal: $showModalNav)
            }).onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "PushedViewNotifciation"))) { _ in
                showModalNav = false
            }
    }
}


struct ModalNavView: View {
    @Binding var parentShowModal: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: PushedView(parentShowModal: $parentShowModal),
                label: {
                    Text("Show Another View")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct PushedView: View {
    @Binding var parentShowModal: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("Pushed View").onTapGesture {
            parentShowModal = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only two levels, and especially if you can dismiss the sheet at multiple levels, you could include `showModal` as a binding variable in your navigation views below, and then toggling it anywhere would dismiss the entire sheet.

I would assume you could do something similar with showModal as an EnvironmentObject as Wei mentioned above - which might be better if there are more than two levels and you only want to dismiss the sheet at the most specific level.

I can't remember if there's some reason to move away from doing this as a binding variable, but it seems to be working for me.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showModal: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.showModal.toggle()
    }) {
      Text("Launch Modal")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, onDismiss: {
      self.showModal = false
    }) {
      // Bind showModal to the corresponding property in PageOneContent
      PageOneContent(showModal: $showModal)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you add showModal as a binding variable in PageOneContent, and it is bound to the state variable in ContentView.

```
struct PageOneContent: View {
  // add a binding showModal var in here
  @Binding var showModal: Bool

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("I am Page One")
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page One")
      .navigationBarItems(
        // bind showModal again to PageTwoContent
        trailing: NavigationLink(destination: PageTwoContent(showModal: $showModal)) {
          Text("Next")
        })
      }
  }
}
```

Finally, in PageTwoContent, you can add showModal here (and in the NavigationLink in PageOneContent, you have bound PageTwoContent's showModal to PageOneContent). Then in your button, all you have to do is toggle it, and it will dismiss the sheet.

```
struct PageTwoContent: View {

  // Add showModal as a binding var here too.
  @Binding var showModal: Bool

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("This should dismiss the modal. But it just pops the NavigationView")
          .padding()

        Button(action: {
          // This will set the showModal var back to false in all three views, and will dismiss the current sheet.
          self.showModal.toggle()
        }) {
          Text("Finish")
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Page Two")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I found out you can actually make showModal into an EnvironmentObject, then simplify toggle the showModal to false on PageTwoContent to dismiss both PageOneContent and PageTwoContent.

Comment: elaborate! or simply leave a comment instead. this is not an answer.