# SwiftUI cannot dismiss sheet containing NavigationView

Tags: swiftui

I have a main View with a NavigationView which can present a sheet. The sheet has also a NavigationView. The sheet can be dismissed with gesture but not with `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`
If a remove the NavigationView from the sheet, it is correctly dismissed.

Could you please advise?

Code for the sheet

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                SheetTitleView(imageName:"gear", title:"Paramètres")
                Divider().padding(.top, -10)
                Form{...}      
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true).statusBar(hidden: false)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
```

```
struct SheetTitleView: View{
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var imageName:String
    var title:String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            if (self.colorScheme == ColorScheme.light){
                Color(UIColor.systemGray4).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            } else{
                Color(UIColor.systemGray6).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
            VStack{
                HStack(){
                    Image(systemName: self.imageName).font(Font.system(.title)).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.darkGray)).padding(.leading, 10)
                    Text(self.title).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.darkGray)).font(.title).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.darkGray)).font(.title).padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Comment: it literally duplicates [previous in tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824443/dismiss-a-parent-modal-in-swiftui-from-a-navigationview)

Comment: see proposed worked approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825996/12299030)

Comment: Yes it answers the issue, thanks

Comment: If it helps you can vote it up so others also see it. Thanks.