# Dismiss presentationMode When log out

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I have a settings view on presentation mode displaying options and its on form view, when I tap on log out it stays on the same page *but I want it to dismiss and go back to the first page*.

[image: This is what the settings view looks like]

**This is the code for the Settings View:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    // Properties
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    // Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                
                // Form
                
                Form{
                    // Section 3
                    Section(header: Text("Account")){
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: OptionsView()) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                
                                HStack {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous).fill(Color.gray)
                                        Image(systemName: "person")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    } // End of ZStack
                                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("Username")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("Username")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                                } // End of HStack
                                
                                
                            } // End of Button
                        } // End of NavigationLink
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: OptionsView()) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                
                                HStack {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous).fill(Color.gray)
                                        Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    } // End of ZStack
                                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("Email")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("Email")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                                } // End of HStack
                            } // End of Button
                        } // End of NavigationLink
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: OptionsView()) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                
                                HStack {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous).fill(Color.gray)
                                        Image(systemName: "mappin")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    } // End of ZStack
                                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("Country")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("Country")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                                } // End of HStack
                            } // End of Button
                        } // End of NavigationLink
                        
                        currencyOptionView()
                        
                        
                        optionView()
                        
                        logOutButton()
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 3)
                    
                    
                    // Section 4
                    
                    Section(header: Text("About the application")){
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "gear", firstText: "Application", secondText: "Todo")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "checkmark.seal", firstText: "Compatibility", secondText: "iPhone, iPad")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "keyboard", firstText: "Developer", secondText: "John / G")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "paintbrush", firstText: "Designer", secondText: "Robort")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "flag", firstText: "Version", secondText: "1.0.0")
                    }.padding(.vertical, 3)
                } // End of form
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
                
                // Footer
                Text("Copyright All rights reserved. \nSultan")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.top, 6)
                    .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                
                
                
            } // End of VStack
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
            }
            )
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
            .background(Color("ColorBackground").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            
            
            
        } // End of Navigation View
        
        
    }
    
    
}



struct optionItems: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let icon: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
}
```

**This is the Log Out Button Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct logOutButton: View {
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @StateObject var profileService = ProfileService()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            } // End of ZStack
            .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
            
            Text("Log Out").foregroundColor(Color(.label))
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                self.session.logout()
                
            }) {}
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
            } // End of HStack
            
    }
}
```

I tried adding `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` to logOutButton() but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This needs to be a minimal, reproducible example. There is too much code in there to work with. Try removing all of the other choices in your `SettingsView`.

Comment: have a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824443/dismiss-a-parent-modal-in-swiftui-from-a-navigationview