# Dismiss Presented view without any click event

Tags: swiftui, navigation, mvp, presentmodalviewcontroller, swiftui-navigationview

I am working with an app in SwiftUI.I have presented one view using

```
.sheet(isPresented: $doIWantThisViewToShowUser, content: {
                            DraggedUsersMenu()
                        })
```

> DraggedUsersMenu()

is view I wanted to present. Here I have few stacks from which I need to navigate to another contentView. Now navigation Works perfectly My 2nd screen is there,but its behind this presented View.
Is there a way to dismiss() this view automatically, once we navigate to another controller.?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825996/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`.

And when you want to dismiss use: `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`